# If $a^m b^n = b^n a^m$ then $ab = ba$

Tags: abstract-algebra

In a group $G$ such that if $a^k = b^k$ for some nonzero integer $k$ then $a = b$,

prove that in $G$ if for some nonzero integer $m, n$, $a^m b^n = b^n a^m$ then $ab = ba$.

I have no idea where to start.

Comment: The first property you state is not true. Let $G$ be the group integers modulo 4 under addition modulo 4. Then $2^2=2+2=4=0$ and $0^2=0+0=0$ but $2\neq 4$.

Comment: Can you explain what $n,m$ and $k$ is?

Comment: $k,m,n$ should at least be nonzero integers.

Comment: Consider the quaternion group $Q$ with $8$ elements. It is generated by two elements $a,b$ of order 4 such that $a^2=b^2, ab=b^3a$. Then they satisfy $a^2b^2=b^2a^2$, but $ab\not=ba$.

Comment: The question has since been edited, and you are of course correct

Comment: Moreover, the property $a^k=b^k\Rightarrow a=b$ is false in any finite group, because $a^{|G|}=b^{|G|}$ for all $a,b\in G$.

Comment: @ÁngelValencia There should really be four variables; the assumption is supposed to hold for all $a,b\in G$, and the conclusion is supposed to hold for all $a',b'\in G$.  The quaternion group does not satisfy the assumptions, for the reason you say (i.e. it's finite).

Comment: @I.Cavey: You confuse multiplicative and additive notation here. $a^k$ implies that the OP uses multiplicative notation. In the group of integers mod 4 with addition this would correspond to $k \cdot a$, and so, indeed, $k \cdot a = k \cdot b \Rightarrow a = b$.

Comment: @Slade Sorry for my out-of-side comment, but I hadn't seen the edition when I posted it. You are right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The edits haven't quite stabilized yet, but I'll assume that $k,m,n$ are nonzero integers.  Otherwise, either the assumption applies only to the trivial group, or the conclusion is false.

Rearranging the given equation, we have $a^m = b^n a^m b^{-n} = (b^nab^{-n})^m$, so $a=b^n a b^{-n}$.

Then, rearranging again, $b^n = a b^n a^{-1} = (aba^{-1})^n$, so $b=aba^{-1}$.