# If $\forall a,b \in G\exists m,n\in\Bbb Z^+$ depending on $a,b$, such that $a^{m}b^{n}=b^{n}a^{m},$ then $G$ is abelian.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

> Let $G$ be a multiplicative group with identity $1$. If for each $a,b \in G $ there exists positive integers $m,n$ depending on $a,b$, such that $a^{m}b^{n}=b^{n}a^{m},$ then $G$ is an abelian group.

Comment: This is not true, for example if $G$ is any finite group we can always take $m=n=|G|$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Even then some additional requirements must be added or the condition would still be satisfied for any finite group.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I meant the formulation of [this duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1550143/if-am-bn-bn-am-then-ab-ba), so indeed we need to assume that $a^k=b^k$ implies $a=b$. This is, however, not very clear there.

Comment: If $R$ is a division ring, $a^{m}b^{n}=b^{n}a^{m}$, for all $a,b \in R$, and appropriate $m,n>0$ depending on $a,b$ , could we get $R$ be a  field?

Answer (score 8):

This is not true. For example you take $G=S_3$ then for any $a,b\in S_3,a^6b^6=b^6a^6$. But as you know $S_3$ is not abelian!